# How does ReadOnlyCollection hide Add and Remove methods

Tags: c#, interface, readonly-collection

`ReadOnlyCollection<T>` realises the `ICollection<T>` interface which has methods like Add and Remove. I know how to hide methods from Intellisense using attributes, but how is it possible to cause an actual compilation error if I try to use these methods?

(Btw, I know it doesn't make sense to call Add and Remove on a ROC, it's a question on causing compilation error for inherited memebers, not on using the correct data structure).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

They're implemented with [*explicit interface implementation*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx), like this:

```
void ICollection<T>.Add(T item) {
    throw NotSupportedException();
}
```

The method is still callable, but only if you view the object as an `ICollection<T>`. For example:

```
ReadOnlyCollection<int> roc = new ReadOnlyCollection<int>(new[] { 1, 2, 3 });
// Invalid
// roc.Add(10);

ICollection<int> collection = roc;
collection.Add(10); // Valid at compile time, but will throw an exception
```

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, by implementing those methods from the `ICollection<T>` interface explicitly, you cannot call them directly.
You'll have to cast the object (the `ReadOnlyCollection` instance) to `ICollection<T>` explicitly.  Then, you can call the Add method.  (Hence, the compiler won't complain, although you'll get a runtime exception).